# Summing up $3+5+9+17+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, geometric-progressions, telescopic-series

> Find the sum of sum of $3
> +5+9+17+...$ till $n$ terms.

Using [Method of differences](http://kineticmaths.com/index.php?title=Summation_of_Series_by_the_Method_of_Differences), the sum of the series is
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n 2^{j-1}+n$$

I am facing difficulty in evaluating $$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n 2^{j-1}$$. How do I do that?

Now I have $2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 ... 2^{n-1}$
The sum of this series is : $2^n- 1$ as sum of GP is given by $a(1-r^n)/(1-r)$.

Here $a = 1, r =2$

Comment: It's a geometric series, with starting term $a = 1$ and common ratio $r = 2$.

Comment: Do you know about sum of geometric series? Have you tried to find a pattern for the sums?

Comment: Editing to add that.

Comment: If you have the answer to your own question (which I think you have) it's still proper to post the question, but you should probably have posted the answer part of it as an answer (it's also considered proper to answer your own question).

Comment: This is the easiest summation in the world: $1,3,7,15,31,63,\cdots$. Add $1$ and see. But youalready solved that, so what ?

Comment: @Abcd I've edited your post to avoid using $n$ for two different things in your formula. In addition, it seems to me that the exponent of $2$ should be $j$ instead of $j-1$, since your sequence starts with $2+1,4+1,8+1,\dots$ I didn't make the change because I wasn't sure it was a typo or a mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe do you mean the following?
$$3+5+9+17+...=\sum_{k=1}^n2^k+n=\frac{2(2^n-1)}{2-1}+n=2^{n+1}-2+n.$$
If so let $S_n=3+5+...+(2^n+1).$

Thus, $$S_n-S_1=\sum_{k=2}^n(S_k-S_{k-1})=\sum_{k=2}^n(2^k+1)=\frac{4(2^{n-1}-1)}{2-1}+n-1,$$
which gives $$S_n=2^{n+1}+n-2.$$

Comment: This result is correct, but unrelated to the main question. These upvotes are undeserved.

Comment: @Abcd I added something. See now.

Comment: @Yves Daoust You are right of course. I fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Without words:**

[image]

$$n+2^{n+1}-2$$

Comment: :) After our current times are so too much talkative ...  it has a really nice meditative appeal to have something explanative without words ...

Answer (score 0):

I had miscalculated earlier. After trying again, I found the error:

So I have $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 2^{k} + n $ instead of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 2^{k-1} + n$

which gives $2^{n+1}+n-2$ using the formula for sum of $n$ terms of GP stated in the question.